# Data Modeling - modeling an Append-only list in NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to make a general purpose data structure. Essentially, it will be an append-only list of updates that clients can subscribe to. Clients can also send updates.

I'm curious for suggestions on how to implement this. I could have a ndb.Model, 'Update' that contains the data and an index, or I could use a StructuredProperty with Repeated=true on the main Entity. I could also just store a list of keys somehow and then the actual update data in a not-strongly-linked structure.

I'm not sure how the repeated properties work - does appending to the list of them (via the Python API) have to rewrite them all?

I'm also worried abut consistency. Since multiple clients might be sending updates, I don't want them to overwrite eachother and lose an update or somehow end up with two updates with the same index.

Comment: When you update a field the whole record is re-written. If you don't need the updates immediately, you could write each new value to a pull queue (include a timestamp), process these and update a repeating property.   Then if the record is full, you can create the next overflow record and do any other processing you need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've a maximum total size for each model in the datastore.

So any single model that accumulates updates (storing the data directly or via collecting keys) will *eventually* run out of space (not sure how the limit applies with regard to structured properties however).

Why not have a model "update", as you say, and a simple version would be to have each provided update create and save a new model. If you track the save date as a field in the model you can sort them by time when you query for them (presumably there is an upper limit anyway at some level).

Also that way you don't have to worry about simultaneous client updates overwriting each other, the data-store will worry about that for you. And you don't need to worry about what "index" they've been assigned, it's done automatically.

As that might be costly for datastore reads, I'm sure you could implement a version that used repeated properties in a single, moving to a new model after N keys are stored but then you'd have to wrap it in a transaction to be sure mutiple updates don't clash and so on.

You can also cache the query generating the results and invalidate it only when a new update is saved. Look at NDB also as it provides some automatic caching (not for a query however).